# Solr's minimum match(mm) and phrase field(pf) match

Tags: solr, lucene, edismax

The minimum match configured in my request handler is 2. My search query contains two terms, i.e. q=termOne termTwo&defType=edismax.

It means that both termOne and termTwo must be found in a document to be considered a match. I also have certain fields specified as qf(query fields) and pf(phrase fields) in the request handler.

Now a document gets a match for termOne in one of the fields defined in the qf and the phrase "termOne termTwo" gets a match for one of the fields defined in pf. Even though it gets these matches, the document will not come in the result as it doesn't satisfy the mm criteria.

Is there any way so that the match in the pf also contributes to the mm and document shows up in the results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[The `pf` parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#pf_.28Phrase_Fields.29) is used to boost results scores where the terms occur in close proximity *after* the set of matching results has already been determined.  If you want the `pf` fields to add documents to the result set, rather than just boost the score, the easiest solution would seem to be to add them into `qf` as well.

Comment: The problem with it is that the field on which it gets a match(say fieldExactMatch), which is defined in pf is keyword tokenized, and hence it is indexed as it is.

So if I add it to qf and go ahead and search for q=termOne termTwo, it will parse it and sent "termOne" & "termTwo" to fieldExactMatch, and in both the cases it wouldn't find the match as it is keyword tokenized and stores "termOne termTwo".